# change function from onclick to onload

Tags: javascript

I have this progress bar which loads once clicked.
How do i change it from onclick to load when the page loads ?

```
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar">
    <div id="label">10%</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 10;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 1200);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
      document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. So whenever `onload` event will occur, your function will be executed. 
P.S. :- Its `always a better approach to keep your javascript code seperate` to the html ( i.e. not to use onload, onclick, etc. attributes in the html tags directly and instead bind the events to the required elements in your javascript code ). This helps in `separating the business logic` from the code and whenever you need to find it or change it, its `comparatively easier to find` if you are dealing with a large code.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 10;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 1200);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
      document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="myProgress">
    <div id="myBar">
      <div id="label">10%</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put it on the body, onload event..

or

If you want to keep things all javascript, you can also use `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', funciton())`

example using body.onload

```js
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 10;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 1200);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
      document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="move()">
  <div id="myProgress">
    <div id="myBar">
      <div id="label">10%</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```